# How to easily convert English audio files to IPA (phonetics) with time stamps on Windows?

Tags: audio, phonetics, phoneme

How would I easily convert English audio files to IPA (phonetic alphabet) with time stamps on Windows?

Everything I find is way out of date. Even similar questions here on stack are out of date. Most stuff doesn't even work anymore, like Python's sphinx.

Or worst of all requires dependencies which would be out of reach for most people or otherwise be for the entirely wrong operating system.

I want to get from my audio files, typically wavs, the phonemes associated with each sound and a time stamp for those spoken phonemes. I am doing this to make it easier for me to model and rig 3d actors.

An example would be the word "Hospital" becoming

```
phonetic_dict = {
    "0.000": "/h/",
    "0.001": "/ɒ/",
    "0.002": "/s/",
    "0.003": "/p/",
    "0.004": "/ɪ/",
    "0.005": "/t/",
    "0.006": "/ə/",
    "0.007": "/l/"
}
```

Of course this is just an example and actual IPA would typically have these phonemes less separated as individual letters, as the sounds matter, the text does not.

I'd prefer something with a GUI that's relatively simple, easy to use and somewhat streamline.

I have looked into Gentle, CMUSphinx, some other stuff on github, even Simon... etc. most of this is either simply outdated, no longer supported, or straight up no longer functions in any capacity or has been yeeted off the face of the earth.

Comment: Hum I'm afraid you did not. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: hum yes, I did. CMU Sphinx is code primarily for python and not all so questions are code thank you v. much.

Comment: @Joe1234 it may be worthwhile engaging with the staff at your institute. I would surprised if the computational linguistics department did not have courses relating to speech-to-text processing.

Comment: I don't go to a university.

Comment: @Joe1234 No worries, it may be worthwhile contacting your local institute. Your question  is a problem that lies in a specific domain. By dovetailing programming with speech processing you will be butting up against problems with both. For instance, you might be better looking first at extracting [diphones](https://speech.zone/courses/speech-processing/module-6-speech-synthesis-waveform-generation-and-connected-speech/videos/diphone/) rather than (mono)phones. You would likely want to look at training a Neural Net / Hidden Markov Model to pickup on distinct diphones.

Comment: At which point, I hope you can appreciate that the answer to the question would likely be quite long. [Speech.zone](https://speech.zone/courses/speech-processing/) is a good resource, but you will probably need someone in that field to help clarify follow-up questions you are likely to have.

Comment: You could also use a [dictionary api](https://dictionaryapi.dev) with whatever text you get as input, but you would restricted to whatever the dictionary says the the phonetics are, rather than what the speaker used, but I imagine that is too simplified a solution from what it looks like you are aiming for.